# NodeJS - sometimes my exported methods aren't available

Tags: node.js, methods, module

This is weird...

I have a module (tools.js) that has a few handy functions in that I like to use, such as stemming or whatever and they are exported in the usual way:

tools.js

```
var stem = function(str) {
    // do some stuff
    return str;
}

module.exports = {
    stem: stem
}
```

And I use this in other modules as you would expect:

```
var tools = require('tools.js');

var someProcess = function(str) {
    return tools.stem(str);
}
```

This works really well... sometimes.

Other times I get an error like:

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'stem'
```

which I would expect if I had no exported my function. But I have, because this exact same piece of code worked fine last time I ran it, I haven't even restarted the process.

Once it breaks I can restart the process and it will be fine, but after a while (and usually after other functions have been called), it breaks. Almost as if there is some namespace stuff going on and it is getting over-written. But I thought Node didn't really suffer from this, as each module is namespaced...

any ideas?

Comment: Your example does not include a reference to "this" but I've seen issues like what you describe when the value of "this" is not what you would expect (e.g. in an async call). Are you referencing this" on your real code?

Comment: I'm not using 'this' at all, the code above is a basic example of what is in my actual code. 

The problem is that sometimes tools.stem() works, othertimes I get the shown error on the EXACT same piece of code.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, it is to do with circular references, addressed here: https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/1694